# OAuthException Error code 458 in Facebook SDK IOS

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, xcode5, facebook-oauth, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using FB SDK VERSION : FBiOSSDK.3.11.1. Here I wanna handle two situations.

1. If FB User removed an App permission in FB Settings , We are getting OAuthException Error code 458. But ,In mobile Facebook setting set to ON for concerned IOS App. How can I handle this , to allow user for Login ?
2. If Mobile setting Facebook Permission is OFF for concerned IOS App , But Facebook settings I have permitted token. status code is 257. How to handle this situation? ( Now I just prompted an Alert says to check FB Permission Settings).

Kindly help me out to explore FBSession for 1st scenario. Thank you in advance